# Custom class ImageView written text ends up behind setImageBitmap

Tags: android, imageview

hi
The custom ImageView is setting a Bitmap like this, in the constructor.

```
setImageBitmap(btm);
```

In my onDraw method im writing text like

```
canvas.drawText
```

Text is showed and I can move the text around using onTouchEvent.

But the text is behind the Bitmap.

I thought setImageBitmap(btm) would be part of the Canvas??
Any ide!

When i draw the Bitmap in onDraw like this, The screen is black!!

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an ImageView that also displays text and you're already handling onDraw, why not just draw the Bitmap manually to the Canvas in onDraw?  That way you have control over the order of the drawing.  Draw the image to the canvas first and then the text, and the text will no longer be obscured by the image.

Comment: When i draw the Bitmap in onDraw like this, The screen is black!!.........canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, null); Also the text is gone , it's all black. Guess it's obvious but i cannot see the mistake

Comment: you have to pass the source and destination rectangles!  Don't just pass 0, 0, and null to the drawBitmap method.

Comment: Where do they come from, I see.....canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)

Comment: ok i see canvas.drawBitmap method has many constructors. Creating the Rect bitmap.getWidth ...but still black screen however. This will be an allnighter for sure

Comment: Are you testing that the bitmap you're trying to draw on the canvas is valid and loaded properly?  You can debug and/or log stuff about the bitmap to make sure that it's being loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Rich. I kind of got it working like this. In constructor im running ...setImageBitmap(btm). And in the onDraw im running ...canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, null);. This is strange but it seems i must run that line in constructor kind of like initiating the imageView(dunno). It's working now i can see text but i have two images, one is centered middle and one is positioned 0,0
Andy ide?

Comment: It depends where you're getting the Bitmap from.  Not being able to look at more relevant code and how you're initializing the Bitmap (both in the constructor and in onDraw), I can only assume either that in one of the two cases the Bitmap isn't properly initialized, or that it gets lost in between the two steps.  It sounds like one of these Bitmaps is pointing at an uninitialized instance.

Comment: because you don't need a paint object to draw a Bitmap